# Rails 4 ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in OrdersController#create

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I m trying to build a shopping cart for a website. I have the cart working so you can add to the cart. The problem I am having is when I try and checkout items in the cart and try to submit my order. I am getting the following error:

> ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in OrdersController#create

along with

> can't write unknown attribute `order_id'

The problem is highlighting this piece of code in my `orders_controller.rb` file

> respond_to do |format|
>         if @order.save
>         Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])         session[:cart_id] = nil

I just cant seem to fix this error.

Below is the create method in my `orders_controller.rb` file

```
def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)

    respond_to do |format|
        if @order.save
            Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
            session[:cart_id] = nil

            format.html { redirect_to store_url, 
                          notice: 'Thank you for your order.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order }
        else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

my migration file

```
class AddOrderToLineItem < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :line_items, :order, :reference
  end
end
```

my order.rb model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, :address, :email, presence: true 
    PAYMENT_TYPES = [ "Check", "Credit card", "Purchase order" ]
  validates :pay_type, inclusion: PAYMENT_TYPES

  def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
      cart.line_items.each do |item|
      item.cart_id = nil
      line_items << item
    end
  end 
end

migration order table
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :address
      t.string :email
      t.string :pay_type

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can we see your order model? - Edit: As in, both the migration and the actual model file itself (only the pertinent parts).

Comment: class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, :address, :email, presence: true 
    PAYMENT_TYPES = [ "Check", "Credit card", "Purchase order" ]
  validates :pay_type, inclusion: PAYMENT_TYPES
  
  def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
      cart.line_items.each do |item|
   item.cart_id = nil
   line_items << item
    end
  end 
end

Comment: Edit your question please.

Comment: sry cant make code block for some reason

Comment: It is four spaces before every line of code. No tabs, so only indent with more spaces. Also, please include your migration, I was hoping to see the columns on this table.

Comment: migration file    class AddOrderToLineItem < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        add_column :line_items, :order, :reference
      end
   end

Comment: 1) again, edit your question, don't post another comment here. 2) I am looking for the migration that created the orders table. If you don't have it, just add a `CREATE TABLE` SQL statement for the table to your question instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think I see the problem. Your migration for orders in line items probably didn't create the `order_id` column you expected, it probably created an `orders` column or something.

Verify that this is the case in the database. If so, undo your previous migration and try this instead:

```
class AddOrderToLineItem < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :line_items, :order_id, :int
  end
end
```

If not, please respond to this answer.

Comment: hi mellowfish87 i added     add_column :line_items, :order_id, :reference
it worked without the int that did the trick thanks for your help i appreciate it